# update database field based on what the user selects via dropdown

Tags: php, html, sql

so on my site, the admin can assign a job to a user and that job will automatically have the status: waiting to be accepted. I have now created a drop down box on the job page so that the user can either decline or accept the job with that drop down box. however im unsure of the coding needed to update the database field based on what the user selects.

what im aiming for is: the user selects a status, then clicks the change button to update the status of the job.

current code:

```
   <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
        { 
            session_start(); 
        } 
    ?>



    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

            <title>Tyre Hire</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css"/>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <header> 
                <img class="img-responsive" src ="images/Logo.png" alt ="logo"/>
            </header>

        </div>
        </div>

                <?php

                require_once ("config.inc.php");

    try
        {
        $conn = new PDO(DB_DATA_SOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        }

    catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
        echo "Oh no, there was a problem" . $exception->getMessage();
        }

                if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
    {
        //user tried to access the page without logging in
        header( "Location: add.php" );

    }

        $login = $_SESSION['user_ID'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_ID = :user_ID"; 
    $term = $conn->prepare($query);
    $term->bindValue(':user_ID', $login);
    $term->execute();

    $login = $term->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);      


    $status = "Waiting to be accepted";
    $status2 = "Accept Job";
    $status3 = "Decline Job";

    if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
    {
        echo "Welcome, you are now logged in as <b>".$_SESSION['username']."</b> <img class='clientView' src='images/loginIcon.png' alt='client'>"; }
        else { 
        echo "You are currently not logged in";
        };

        ?>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
        <br>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.php">Tyre Hire</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li><a href="main.php"> Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="search.php"> Search <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
                    <li><?php echo "<a href='all-jobs.php?user_id=" . $login->user_ID . "&occupation=". $login->occupation ."''> Current Jobs <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-print'></span></a>";?> </li>
                     <li><a href="interest.php"> Register Interest <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="logout.php"> Logout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="account.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="add.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="right">
                <h2>Current Jobs</h2>
                <p>One of the best sites to find the best qualified and skilled drivers in the UK.</p>


                            <form class="form-horizontal formApply"  action="" method="POST">
            <h2><u>Job Details </u></h2>

        <div class="form-group">

    <?php

        echo "<h3>Job role :".$worker->jobTitle."</h3>";

    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<h3> About the role </h3>";
    echo "<li><b>Company Name:</b>".$worker->company."</li>";

    echo "<li><b>Job Description:</b>".$worker->jobDescription."</li>";
    echo "<h3>shift pattern</h3>";
    echo "<li><b>Start Time: </b>".$worker-> startTime."</li>";
    echo "<li><b>End Time: </b>".$worker-> endTime."</li>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<li><b>start Date:</b>".$worker->startDate."</li>";
    echo "<li><b>Job Expiry Date:</b>".$worker->expiry."</li>";
    echo "<b><h4>Current Status: </b>".$worker->status."</h4>";
    echo "</ul>";




    ?>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="search"> Status</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">

            <select class="form-control" name="status" > 
            <option value="<? echo $status;?>"><?php echo $status;?></option>
            <option value="<? echo $status2;?>"><?php echo $status2;?></option>
            <option value="<? echo $status3;?>"><?php echo $status3;?></option>
            </select> 

            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $status; ?>" name="status">

    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
 <!--<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="search"></label>      -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">

    <!--    <select class="form-control" name="status" > 
        <option value="<? echo $job;?>"><?php echo $job;?></option>
        </select>  -->

        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $job; ?>" name="job_id">

</div>
</div>

    </div>
    <input class = "buttonA" type="submit" name="Apply" value="Change status"/> 
            </div>          







    </form>

            </div>  


            </div>
            </div>




            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="BottomArea">
            <h4> Recruitment Agencies </h4> 
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img class="FxPic img-responsive" src="images/fxpic.png" alt="fx-logo">
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img class="driverhire img-responsive"  src="images/driverhire.jpg" alt="driverhire">
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img class="logi img-responsive" src="images/logi.png" alt="logi-logo">
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img class="pebble img-responsive" src="images/noel.png" alt="pebbles">
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
            <footer>
            <img id="logoFoot" src ="images/Logo.png" alt ="logo"/>
                <p><b>Address: 5A twickenham road, london SJ5 7AE</b></p>
            </footer>
            </div>
            </div>

            <script src=myjs.js></script>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

attempted it after reading the update manual, no errors but upon clicking the button it gives a blank page.:

```
   <?php
include ("db_fncs.php");
try{
       $conn = new PDO(DB_DATA_SOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

}
catch (PDOException $exception) 
{
echo "Oh no, there was a problem" . $exception->getMessage();
}


$status = $_POST["status"];
$job = $_POST['job_id'];
print_r($_POST);

$query = "UPDATE jobs SET status = :status WHERE job_id = :job_id AND status = :status";


    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':status', $status);
$stmt->bindValue(':job_id', $job);
    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();
    //$stmt->commit();
 echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Start with the manual on UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html then update your post to contain what you tried and may have failed.

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic syntax for UPDATE is:

```
UPDATE <my_table>
SET <update_column_name> = <some_value>
WHERE <identifying_column_name> = <some_value>
```

In your case, it would probably look something like:

```
UPDATE jobs
SET status = <new_job_status>
WHERE userid = <user_id>
AND jobid = <job_id>
```

Comment: thanks, gave this a go but it doesnt seem to be updating the field, updated the code

Comment: This line `UPDATE jobs SET status = status WHERE job_id = job_id` is going to set `status = status`, in other words it won't make any change.  You need to update it to use the actual variable values on the right side of the equals sign, something like: `UPDATE jobs SET status = $new_status WHERE job_id = $job_id`. The `$new_status` and `$job_id` values need to come from your application code.

Comment: well in this situation, im only storing the status in a variable ($status). as for the job_id im unsure of where to collect it from. like would i have to do a pre-sql query to get the job id and then combine? or is there a less complicated way as when I bring up the job at first, i just use the worker variable as shown above.

Comment: When you render your "assign job" page, you have to know which specific job you are talking about.  In your code, you have `echo "<h3>Job role :".$worker->jobTitle."</h3>";`  So, you are displaying info specific to this job, I assume.  Where does the data for `$worker` come from?  See if you can find a field similar to `job_id` in this variable, and then pass that down to your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: ok so the url of the current page is binded with the job_id i.e. ``http://localhost/finalyear/job-list.php?job_id=62``.  but when using get in the sql statement, its saying that the job_id is undefined. any ideas?

Comment: Your SQL looks OK, but you should parameterize/bind all variables to be consistent.  The two things I can suggest to verify are: 1) Make sure you're getting a value in your `$job_id` variable, when you read it from GET/POST, and 2) that value stored in `$job_id` is being passed to your SQL statement.  Another idea is to pass `job_id` as an `<input type="hidden">` form field.

Comment: it doesnt seem to like the bind statement for status.error: ``Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens``

Comment: Are you still using this - `$query = "UPDATE jobs SET status = $status WHERE job_id = :job_id";`?  If so, try updating the `$status` parameter syntax to match the syntax for the `:job_id` parameter: `$query = "UPDATE jobs SET status = :status WHERE job_id = :job_id";`

Comment: tried that aswell, "0 records updated." I've tested it with print_r and its definitely getting the values, its just not updating the table for some reason

Comment: Hmm...if it's not saving, then maybe your DB session is not in auto-commit mode.  Try adding a `commit()` statement at the end: `$stmt->commit()`, right after the `execute()`

Comment: doesnt seem to recognised that command, ill update my code again

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$conn->commit()`.  If that still doesn't work, take a look at these examples: 1) http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php, 2) http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: The way it works with a DB transaction is you create a session, prepare a SQL statement, apply any parameter values, execute the query, commit (i.e. permanently save) the changes to the DB...if your query isn't erroring out and you are passing the values correctly, then it's most likely the changes are not getting committed.